# Unencrypted Database Mirroring connections despite correct endpoint and service configuration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Despite correct installation/configuration (in my opinion) the query ...

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT [net_transport]
    , [protocol_type]
    , [encrypt_option]
    , [auth_scheme]
  FROM [master].[sys].[dm_exec_connections];
```

... returns FALSE in the [encrypt_option] column for the protocol type "Database Mirroring":

[image: screenshot query results]

I have successfully ...

- installed and configured 2 SQL Server instances (SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition),
- configured "Force Encryption" to "Yes" in the protocol properties (SQL Server Configuration Manager),
- set up the required endpoints with the `ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM AES` option and
- set up an availability group.

The instance uses a self-generated certificate that is created during startup. However, I have the same picture in another cluster where explicitly generated certificates (AD) are used.

What have I possibly missed?

I found a similar, but also still unanswered question here: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/unencrypted-connections-in-availability-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... returns FALSE in the [encrypt_option] column for the protocol type "Database Mirroring"

Unfortunately it's a limitation of the DMV, this doesn't mean the connection isn't encrypted. You can verify this with a packet capture.

Comment: Phew, thanks! I didn't really want to believe in a bug or limitation. Is this limitation documented somewhere (SQLDocs, ...)?

Comment: It is not. I was going to update the DMV to show status of other endpoint types but I left the team before I was able to do so.